# RStudio OSX - trouble using dictionary

Tags: dictionary, rstudio

I have trouble with the dictionary in `RStudio`. 
It looks like it is installed and everything but the spelling mistakes are not highlighted or anything.

Any clue ?

I work on a mac `OS X Yosemite`.

[image: Snapshot here]